# Какие нужны сертификаты для того чтобы сайт мог получить доступ к устройствам (Android, OS X)

Tags: android, macos, ssl

В общем вопрос в заголовке.
Какие нужны сертификаты чтобы сайт мог получить доступ к камере, микрофону и динамикам мобильного устройства (Android, OS X) Сайт работает по https

На компьютере все нужные устройства подключаются без проблем. На телефонах ошибка внутреннего приложения (Подключение не удалось)